# Where are the rules for how to create a Dhampyr PC?

Tags: character-creation, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, product-identification

I've seen Dhampyr mentioned occasionally but I don't seem to be able to find rules for creating one. As far as I know they're not the same as 15th gen vampires, unless I'm mistaken.

Where are the rules for creating a Dhampyr?

Ideally I'd like the 20th anniversary version rules but if there aren't any then previous versions would be fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 20th anniversary rules version of the dhampir are in [Beckett's Jyhad Diary](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/225322/V20-Becketts-Jyhad-Diary), on page 144. Earlier rules could be found in "[Half-Damned: Dhampyr](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565042476)."

Comment: You forgot Time of the Thin Bloods where they said Dhampires are just Revenants born instead of created. Though BJD said Dhampir and Ghouls are two different things and a Dhampir can not be ghouled, though he can be Blood bounded.

Answer (score 8):

Well, first I have to distinguish between "Dhampyr" and "Dhampir", just because it can be confusing.

**Dhampir:** They're "mortals" born of one Thin-Blood (ONLY 15th generation) and a human. They do not suffer the Curse of Caine, but they can't develop disciplines up from one. You can find information of creating Thin-Blood vampires and Dhampir characters on "The Time of The Thin Blood".

**Dhampyr:** They're almost the same as the Dhampir, but the difference is that they are born of the Kue-Jin, not the Thin-Blood Vampires. As Jadasc had said, the information for creating a character can be found in "Half-Damned: Dhampyr".

There are no rules for V20, but you can just use, in the case of the Dhampir, the character sheets for the V20, as long as Dhampir are almost the same as a Ghoul. In the case of Dhampyr, I found the sheet for V20 version, you can find them [here](http://mrgone.rocksolidshells.com/pdf/KotE/KotE2-Page_V20_Dhampyr_Editable.pdf)*. There are no rules, but an actualized sheet.

*This comes from [MrGone Sheets](http://mrgone.rocksolidshells.com), a master god of world of darkness sheets.

Comment: Aren't male 14th Generation capable to become fathers?

Comment: No, they aren't as far as I know.

Comment: Not anymore. Though 16th Generations are possible of bringing them to live too.

Answer (score 1):

The process for creating a Damphyr is described in "Half-Damned: Dhampyr" but a thorough understanding of Kuei-jin is recommended for character interactions.

Damphyr can in some ways be compared to ghouls, although the similarities end pretty quickly. For starters, Damphyr have a P'o which makes a Damphyr unable to be Blood Bonded. Also, because of the Joss a Damphyr will act much more bold and impulsive (since such risks usually pay-off for them).

Damphyr are also known by some of the more-informed Kuei-jin to be the Golden Children (Jin Hai), so Damphyr are normally looked down on by the Kuei-jin, although some philosophers think the Golden Children may one day redeem the Kuei-jin (which could be a very interesting plot, albeit a long one involving the turning of the Wheel of Ages).

Answer (score 1):

They are in Beckett's Jyhad Diary on Page 144.